# How to nest nightwatch.js commands in page sections?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

I have a page `pages/login.js` looks like:

```
function fillAndSubmitLogin(email, password) {
  return this
  .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
  .setValue('@emailInput', email)
  .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
  .waitForElementVisible('@loginSubmitButton')
  .click('@loginSubmitButton');
}


export default {
  commands: [
    fillAndSubmitLogin
  ],
  elements: {
    emailInput: 'input#email',
    passwordInput: 'input[type=password]',
    TFAInput: 'input#token',
    loginSubmitButton: '.form-actions button.btn.btn-danger'
  }
};
```

I have another page `pages/hompage.js` homepage.js attempts to include `pages/login.js` as a section

```
import login from "./login.js";

module.exports = {
  url: 'http://localhost:2001',
  sections: {
    login: {
      selector: 'div.login-wrapper',
      ...login
    }
  }
};
```

I then have a test case that attempts to login on the hompage section

```
  'Homepage Users can login': (client) => {
    const homepage = client.page.homepage();
    homepage
    .navigate()
    .expect.section('@login').to.be.visible;


    const login = homepage.section.login;
    login
    .fillAndSubmitLogin('user@test.com', 'password');

    client.end();
  }
```

This test then fails with the following error

```
TypeError: login.fillAndSubmitLogin is not a function
       at Object.Homepage Users can login (/Users/kevzettler//frontend/test/nightwatch/specs/homepage.spec.js:32:6)
       at <anonymous>
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)

  login.fillAndSubmitLogin is not a function
       at Object.Homepage Users can login (/Users/kevzettler//frontend/test/nightwatch/specs/homepage.spec.js:32:6)
       at <anonymous>
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Nightwatch docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects), any commands that are exported in page objects should be plain JavaScript objects with a key being a command name and the value being a function.  For example:

```
var googleCommands = {
  submit: function() {
    this.api.pause(1000);
    return this.waitForElementVisible('@submitButton', 1000)
      .click('@submitButton')
      .waitForElementNotPresent('@submitButton');
  }
};

module.exports = {
  commands: [googleCommands],
  elements: //...etc ...
  // etc...
}
```

In this example, the module exports `googleCommands`, which is a command object which has a key (*submit*) and a corresponding function.  I believe you should refactor your code as follows:

```
function fillAndSubmitLogin = {
  fillAndSubmitLogin: function(email, password) {
    return this
    .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
    .setValue('@emailInput', email)
    .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
    .waitForElementVisible('@loginSubmitButton')
    .click('@loginSubmitButton');
  }
};
```

Of course, you don't have to make the command name the same in both places (as the example shows (`googleCommands`/`submit`).  This allows you to expose a variety of functions in one `command`.  Hope that answers the question!